# How do I use SSL with Amazon S3 CNAME masked buckets?

Tags: ssl, amazon-s3, cname-record

I am successfully running an Amazon S3 bucket as media.mydomain.com. The problem is, I'm running an https site and I'm unable to link to files using https//media.mydomain.com. How can I switch to using SSL?

I'm using Laravel Forge + Digital Ocean for hosting and deployment, in case that matters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to pay for cloudfront+ssl in order for that to work. There is no way you can serve a s3 bucket wiith your own domain.

You can use amazon's https host for your bucket though and that would work.

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to use or can use CloudFlare and don't need CloudFront capabilities this can be achieved with ease. Site users can access the site on HTTPS via CloudFlare, while CloudFlare accesses the S3 resources on HTTP, it's called CloudFlare flexible SSL.

[image]

You need to add a CNAME on Cloudflare DNS to your S3 bucket and change SSL to flexible on CloudFlare and get things to work.

If you need more help on this, visit [S3 CNAME SSL With CloudFlare](https://anands.github.io/blog/2018/09/16/s3-cname-ssl-with-cloudflare/) (FYI: Links points to my article on my blog, which has a little more things in detail).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this now without paying a fortune.

http://knightlab.northwestern.edu/2015/05/21/implementing-ssl-on-amazon-s3-static-websites/

Comment: I dont think Laravel should be hosted as a static website. He may need S3 as a storage driver only

Answer (score 0):

Read [this answer](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=169951) - Buckets with periods will cause an invalid SSL certificate and you should use dashes instead if you want to mask S3 and your subdomain

Comment: Link is no longer publicly available